# Is it possible to get a copy of the Dead Sea Scrolls texts?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, internet

I'm interested in getting a copy of the Dead Sea Scrolls texts (preferably digital.)  I'm basically looking for [this](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/), except the text of the Dead Sea Scrolls instead of the Masoretic.  Pictures of the text wouldn't suffice for my purposes.  Where might this be available?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is possible to view digital copies of some of the scrolls on [this website](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive), which is maintained by the Israel Antiquities Authority.

I don't know if they have all the scrolls yet, but I believe that they intend to have all of them up there, eventually.

Comment: I think he was asking for the TEXTS of the DSS, not pictures of the scrolls. As far as I know, there is no place online that lets you read those texts for free...

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton Maybe. I don't know if those exist anywhere. Not hearing back from the OP, I think this still answers the question as phrased.

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton -- that's correct.  I'd like to study them in lieu of the Masoretic.  Do you know if they are available in that capacity?